# Flutter get current route name, of Navigator, from GlobalKey

Tags: flutter, navigator

In my Flutter application I need to know the current path to avoid pushing the same path twice.

I found that I can use the following code:

```
    ModalRoute.of(context).settings.name
```

It works, but only for the main Navigator.

Since I have a second Navigator in my app that I target with a GlobalKey, how can I access its current path?

I tried like this:

```
ModalRoute.of(HomePage.navigatorKey.currentContext).settings.name
```

But it returns the main route.

Comment: Can you gives us more context into why you decided to use a 2nd Navigator, and how you are using it?

Comment: I use it inside another widget to perform subnavigation. I don't think other context is required. I just need to know how to access the current route of a Navigator which I know the GlobalKey.

Comment: @L.Gangemi did u ever find a solution to this?

Comment: I don't remember founding a solution. I suggest you to take a look at some routing package like this one: https://pub.dev/packages/routemaster

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if you still need it but here is my solution to problem.

```
String route = "";
HomePage.navigatorKey.currentContext!.popUntil((currentRoute) {
  route = currentRoute.settings.name;
  // Return true so popUntil() pops nothing.
  return true;
});
```